# Connection error with MongoMapper: Operation failed with the following exception: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, mongomapper

We're on mongodb 2.0.0, mongo gem 1.4.1, mongo_mapper 0.9.2, rails 3.0.6.

If we try refreshing a page after a while (e.g., 10 min), we see the following error:

```
Mongo::ConnectionFailure (Operation failed with the following exception: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.
```

Is there some configuration setting we need to adjust to extend connections?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Downgrade to mongo(/bson/bson_ext) 1.3.1. 1.4.0 and 1.4.1 have "critical bugs" in them.

http://groups.google.com/group/mongodb-user/browse_thread/thread/7ddaabe02d43fbab?pli=1

> Users are reporting unusually high numbers of connections, performance 
>   problems, and 
>   threading issues in 1.4.0 and 1.4.1. There's also a bug in sending 
>   commands to the correct 
>   node in 1.4.1.

Comment: Thanks, Chris! Hope 1.4.2 is released soon, though the release date seems unclear based on the thread ...

Comment: Yeah, I'm hoping it shows up soon, too. 1.3.1 is serving me well enough for the time being, but the gem getting yanked really spooked me, so I'm gonna wait for a bit before I go back to 1.4.2 once it's out.

Comment: Is there anything special we need to do to revert to 1.3.1? Just update the GEMFILE and run bundle install? Anything else?

Comment: That should do it. I don't think there were any major interface changes. Just make sure that you specify versions for mongo, bson, and bson_ext, or else you'll get version mismatch errors.

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean exactly by this? Outside the GEMFILE or within the GEMFILE?

Comment: Hi Chris, would you mind clarifying what you meant by specifying versions for mongo, bson, and bson_ext?